# Adding latency to outbound UDP packets with tc

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I would like to impose an arbitrary latency on outbound UDP packets using a fw filter in tc; however, I cannot get the filter to work properly:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:3 handle 30: netem delay 200ms
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 3 handle 1 fw flowid 1:3

iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

If I use the following u32 filter instead I get the desired effect:

```
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 3 u32 match ip dport 53 0xffff flowid 1:3
```

I don't wish to use the u32 filters, and what is more troubling I can't get the `--ttl-set` or `--set-tos` manglers to work in Ubuntu 10.04.

The two may be completely unrelated, but I am concerned that the packets aren't being marked by iptables. I have been unable to find a way to test marking.

Comment: Doing a `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j LOG` after your MARK line will log the packet to syslog, and part of the log message will be the current mark value - hopefully that will help with debugging.

Comment: Just noticed - you're marking inbound packets, but trying to add latency to outbound packets... or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended solving my problem with another feature of `iptables` instead of `--set-mark`:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:3
```

I hope this helps someone as I toiled over the complexities of `tc` for sometime before accomplishing this seemingly simple task.

**EDIT:**

Andy Smith is correct, I should have been marking the POSTROUTING chain! The following rule should work with `--set-mark`:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 1
```